# Transaction Handling in database

Tags: database, transactions

How do databases such as MySQL, PostgreSQL handle transactions when there are a lot of transactions come to? How do they identity transaction's order?

Comment: What do you mean by order?

Comment: @NathanHughes For example, trans A, trans B, trans C come to database at the same time with trans A is first, B is second one and C is third one. How does it identity transaction's order?

Answer (score 0):

Databases process transactions as they come in concurrently. The only order is whatever random order the requests happen to arrive in on the server.

The database server can always prioritize requests however it wants. But its goal is maximizing throughout while respecting isolation levels, it doesn’t care about prioritizing one kind of application business logic over another.

For the database clients to impose an order they would have to control the timing in which they submit the transactions to the database. If you want A to precede B, have B check if the results of A are present, and if not then rollback (and provide a way for B to retry). Or put A and B together in a stored procedure.  For batch jobs, some scheduling of when the different jobs get executed  is normal, where it’s specified some batch job will occur at a given time of day.